# JSTL - Loop through table rows and set background color at each oneven rows

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl

The purpose (according to the forEach loop) is to set a background color in every 3 rows inside the table.
My code below doesnt work.
The tabel is returning properly with all datas inside but no colors are set.

```
<c:forEach var="coffee" items="${collection}">

<tr  class="${status.count % 3 == 0 ? 'even' : 'oneven'}"
${status.count % 3 == 0 ? 'even' : 'oneven'}  >
<td> ${coffee.brand} </td>
<td> ${coffee.type} </td>
<td> ${coffee.country} </td>

</tr>

</c:forEach>
```

My CSS class

```
tr.even { background: red; }
tr.odd { background: green; }
```

Thank you for your help.

I found my answer:

```
<h2>tabel with changing colors</h2>

    <table border=1>

        <tr>
            <th>Brand</th>
            <th>type</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>

        <c:forEach var="coffees" items="${collection}" varStatus="status">



            <tr class="${status.count % 3 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}"
                ${status.count % 3 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}>
                <td>${coffees.brand}</td>
                <td>${coffees.type}</td>
                <td>${coffees.country}</td>

            </tr>

            </c:forEach>



    </table>
```

Comment: Confirm that "even" is actually a class that is defined for tr elements in the CSS.

Comment: Is "varStatus" of "forEach" assigned to "status"?

Comment: Is the css `class` attribute properly set in the `<tr>`? Also your css seems to be for `<li>` element instead of the `<tr>` element of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status` is an undefined attribute here. You need to define it using the `varStatus` attribute of the `forEach` tag:

```
<c:forEach var="coffee" items="${collection}" varStatus="status">
```

Also `color` is used to set the foreground (text) color. Not to set the background color. And you apply the class to `li`, so it doesn't apply to table rows and cells. The CSS should be:

```
tr.even td {
    background-color: #006699;
}

tr.oneven td {
    background-color: #009999; 
}
```